# Get data from three tables with library-table between

Tags: php, mysql, select, query-optimization

I have tree tables:

table `user_products`

```
user_id | product_specific_id | order_no
   1    |         1           |    1
   1    |         2           |    1
   1    |         3           |    2
```

table `products_library`

```
product_specific_id | product_id
   1                |    3
   2                |    3
   3                |    1
```

table `product_names`

```
product_id | name
   1       |    prod1
   2       |    prod2
   3       |    prod3
```

Every product in the database does have unique `product_id`. But when user does order any product, he can modify it, so I created `product_specific_id` that I'm using in `user_products`, and table `products_library` where I can translate every unique `product_specific_id` to the base `product_id`.

Now every `product_specific_id` does have name of related `product_id`, that I do store in table `product_names`.

Now I need to display the name of every `product_specific_id` for specific `user_id`and `order_no`.

Expected result should look like this:

```
user_id | order_no | product_specific_id | name
   1    |    1     |           1         | prod3
   1    |    1     |           2         | prod3
```

I'm able to fit in two queries: first I'm selecting list of `product_specific_id` from `user_products`, and than I'm nesting `SELECT` like

```
SELECT name 
FROM product_names 
WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id 
                     FROM products_library 
                     WHERE product_specific_id IN (...)
```

But is it possible to fit everything it in one query? I have no idea how such thing could be achieved, if at all. Also, I'm not sure if nesting queries like this is good or not in the first place. Perhaps is it just fine to get it in two queries and nesting queries too much is bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below way using just JOIN

```
select user_id,order_no,u.product_specific_id,name
from user_products u join products_library p on u.product_specific_id=p.product_specific_id
join product_names pn on p.product_id=pn.product_id
where user_id=1 and order_no=1
```

Comment: Hey, it's not only possible, but not so complicated as well. Thank You a lot! Please make here a little fix: `join product_names on` => `join product_names pn on`

Comment: @Zorann, I've fixed it - you can check now